# DagreD3 SVG g element width narrower than needed

Tags: css, svg

I am working on SVG Graph (Dagre D3) and in my SVG code parent `g` element (with class edgeLabel) looks narrower than its required size and than its children. This causes message on my label not fit into (see screenshot)

[image: SCREENHOT]

So the required width is 152.5 (for `foreignObject`) but I see in my browser (latest Chrome) 137.25 which is not good. I tried to change some CSS styles (width, min-width etc.) but it did not work. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD_1**

`g` parent looks like the following:

[image: picture]

its size is bigger than its child `edgeLabel` which causes problem

**UPD_2**

anyway, the size of 152 is enough to display the content. If we manually increase the width, it will show up, but still the size of the container will be smaller than needed:

[image]

Comment: That's not possible <g> elements autosize to their children always. Your problem is elsewhere. Is the <g> element's ultimate parent large enough?

Comment: yes, it`s parent is bigger, pls see update to the question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Images of code are not useful.